# SQL Server c# connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

So Im running a Sql Server 2012 in a virtual machine on my computer and I want to be able to connect on it with the SqlConnection on Visual Studio, but I have no idea what to put on the servername parameter.

I dont know if I have to put the vm ipaddress or the machine address "WIN-NIJ53etc\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: Have you tried any of the two?

Comment: can you connect to database on the vm? (like with sql server management studio)

Comment: What is the virtual machine software you use?

Comment: Im using Vmware workstation. I can connect using sql server managment studio using the machine address "WIN-NIJ53etc\SQLEXPRESS" as server name. But I want to be able to connect from outside this computer too, thats why i think the machine address is not useful for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

**FOR MIGRATING BETWEEN SQL CE AND SQL SERVER: Please take a look at this instruction [here](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20ErikejBlogsAboutSqlCompactnetAndRelatedStuff%20%28Everything%20SQL%20Server%20Compact%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader).**

You should follow these steps:

**1- Set the virtual machine to have a physical IP address.**

For configuring network on Microsoft Virtual PC: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833134

**2- Be sure that you can see the VM with a static IP address.** (ping is a good idea for checking that, but don't forget to turn off the firewall on the target machine, I mean the machine you wanna ping. There is no need for the server to see the client, so check that your client (in this case your VM) can ping the server IP address like `"ping 192.168.10.1 -t"`)

**3- Use Configuration Manager (All Programs\Microsoft SQL Server\Configuration Tools) and set SQL port and visibility over network.**

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189083(v=sql.105).aspx

**4- Restart the SQL server.**

**5- Be sure that `"SQL Server Browser"` service is started.** (incase you wanna use the instance name to access the SQL server)

**6- Config the firewall on the host machine (machine that has SQL engine) and add the port  you specified in the Configuration Manager to TCP Inbound rules.**

Take a look at here: http://www.tavislovell.com/post/How-to-configure-Windows-Firewall-to-allow-access-to-SQL-Server.aspx

BUT be advised that you should set the port specified in the Configuration Manager (default is 1433 but sometimes it's dynamic and you should set it again)

**7- After you set the port and network visibility, you should change the `"Server"` value in the connection string to this format `"IPAddress, PORT"` like `"192.168.10.50, 1433"`** (When you specify the port, there is no need to set the instance name like this `"192.168.10.50\SQLEXPRESS"`)

Hope it helps

Comment: Mohammad, if I follow those steps will i be able to connect to the Sql Sever outside this computer?

Comment: You can set configurations in the way for others either to see or not. What do you want?

Comment: This configurations is not related to that settings. You should set an IP range for the rule if you want to limit IPs that can see the specified port on your computer.

Comment: When i was using a local database i used a connection like this SqlCeConnection Conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + "|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf"); But now i am running the sql sever on a vm, what i want is to be able to connect with the sever from a ip using SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Severaddress = XXXX", user, pw) but i dont know what to put in the server address parameter, thats my main question. Im afraid if i put "WIN-NIJ53etc\SQLEXPRESS" the client from outside wont connect since it wont recognize this address

Comment: Show me your exact connection string value. I will change that for you and I'll help you to do that. ;)

Comment: Ooooooops! Sorry, it's your complete connection string. Because you're using SQL CE! Not SQL Server. Do you have a version of SQL Server installed?

Comment: This SQLCe is my old local database and thats my old connection string thats my problem. Im trying to adapt it now to my new Sql Sever 2012 database using SqlConnection.

Comment: Just want to thank you anyway for trying to help me out, i really appreciate that :)

Comment: I think you should take a look at here: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/how-migrate-databases-between

It's my gift to you. It's all in Visual Studio. If you had any question please ask. Cheers

Comment: You go try solve the problem, then I would be happy. I haven't done anything so far. ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ahh the joys of SQL Server Installation setup.

Make sure you have:

- Network communication between the VM and the client computer (ping will work)
- The SQL Server Service configured to start automatically or that it is started
- The service configured to use TCP (if you don't want to use Named Pipes)
- Either the SQL Server Browser enabled and started or that a static port is configured (1433 or similar)
- The firewall rules configured to allow 1433 (or the port you have chosen) and 1434 (if you are using browser)
- The connection string using the proper format Computer Name\Instance (to use browser) or Computer Name,port (if you are using a static port

There is a good [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) on MSDN that may prove helpful.  With specific regard to the Server Name/IP question, it doesn't matter so long as the client computer can resolve it.  If you are testing, "IP,Port" is the most reliable (E.g. 10.10.10.100,1433) as it does not depend on NetBIOS, DNS nor the SQL Browser service.